# Looping behavior of Twilio's Dial verb

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to get Twilio to dial a number and receive the outcome of the call - no-answer, busy, complete and so forth. The implementation is pretty straight forward:

```
@app.route('/dial', methods=['GET','POST'])
def Dial():
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    number = <Phone_number_to_call>
    with resp.dial(action='/call_status', timeout='15') as r:
        r.number(number)

    return str(resp)

@app.route('/call_status', methods=['GET','POST'])
def CallStatus:
    call_status = request.values.get('DialCallStatus', None)
    print call_status
```

The script works fine until the dialed side wants to screen my call. When this happens, Twilio redials the number instead of sending a busy signal. Twilio continues to do this everytime the other side screens the calls until it reaches the set timeout. Deleting the timeout did not help and the script continued with this action.

Looking through the Dial verb's docs on Twilio or in other questions in this and other forums did not give me an answer or a clue as how to tackle this problem or where even where to start.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "screen my call"?

Comment: If I get Twilio to call a cellphone, and the other side does not accept my call - "hangs-up" the call before answering. This action is supposed to send a "busy" signal back, but for some reason Twilio doesn't recognize the signal and continues dialing

Comment: So if the dialed party does not answer the phone call, then wouldn't the call likely continue to ring until it gets picked up by that callers voicemail?  Even if there was no voicemail system, I'm not sure I see how that would result in the phone call returning a busy status.  The "busy" status that we would get back from the called parties carrier is only sent if the number you are calling is presently already on a phone call *and* does not have a forward to either voicemail or some other number set up.

Comment: Your right - the call is supposed to get picked up by voicemail, unless the dialed party doesn't have it - this is the case I am trying to understand. If the dialed party screens my call, what status is supposed to be sent (I thought it was a "busy" status) and how do I handle it on Twilio?

Comment: As I understand it, if the dialed party simply ignores the call, the call will continue to ring until either Twilios <Dial> timeout is reached (30 seconds is the default) or, if they have it configured, the call gets picked up by their voicemail.  In the first scenario (the timeout is reached) I would expect the call status to be 'no-answer'.  In the second where its picked up by voicemail, the status will be 'in-progress' and then 'completed'.